# Point in multiple circles in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

My use case is one of defined service area or the inverse of the *nearest neighbor* query. I have a database of service providers each willing to work within N miles (radius) of a point. On the flip side I have users each at a given point looking for service providers that can provide service to their location. Another way to think about this could be restaurant delivery.

If I specify an address, how do I match it to supported delivery areas?

Some might be have a 5 mile radius, some might have 40 mile radius defined in the DB. I say this is the *inverse* of the nearest neighbor because each "neighbor" in this case has their own definition of how far they are willing to travel from a point, which is more important than how far each is from the customer's point (address).

I'm looking for some SQL query examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple proximity search with dynamic radius, using `ST_DWithin`:

```
SELECT sa.<id>
FROM   <service_areas> AS sa
WHERE  ST_DWithin(
         sa.<geom>,
         <customer_geom>,
         sa.<radius>
       )
;
```

**Note:**

`sa.<radius>` will be treated as **unit of CRS** (so if your values are given in *miles*, but the data is referenced in EPSG:4326, a value of 10 *miles* would be treated as a proximoty of 10 *degrees*!)

Make sure your data is transformed into a suitable projection, or use the `GEOGRAPHY` type to work with **meter**:

```
SELECT sa.<id>
FROM   <service_areas> AS sa
WHERE  ST_DWithin(
         sa.<geom>::GEOGRAPHY,
         <customer_geom>::GEOGRAPHY,
         sa.<radius_in_meter>
       )
;
```

*You can use an expression like `sa.<radius> * 1609` in the function.*

The `GEOGRAPHY` type is only avalable if your data is represented in a geographic reference system (LonLat). The results are highly precise due to the underlying spheroidal math used in computations.

---

These queries benefit massively from a spatial index on `<service_areas>.<geom>`! If you choose an on-the-fly cast to `GEOGRAPHY`, use a functional index like so:

```
CREATE INDEX ON <service_areas>
  USING GIST (CAST(<geom> AS GEOGRAPHY))
;
```

Comment: Needless to say, without true network routing, a radius search is dangerous: while the opposite shore of a Great Lake may well be within a 10 Miles radius, driving there would take you a day...

Comment: yes of course, this is currently a very simple operation, which does not take into account actual driving distance. Thanks.